# Does "rm -rf $dir" ever return false?

Tags: rm, exit-status

I've written the following line of code to delete the contents of a directory.

`rm -rf $dir && mkdir -p $dir`

However, this will not work if the first statement failed. Does it ever return 1?

Comment: For what it is worth, this is __very dangerous__ code. Make sure you sanitize the `$dir` variable and handle it if it is not set.

Comment: Considering the desired end state with `rm -rf <dir>` is to clear out anything that's there, is it really an error? The assumption you're going into `mkdir` with is still true if it wasn't there to begin with. If it really bothers you, you can remove `-f` which won't ignore non-existent files.

Comment: I would *at the very least* do two sanity checks:  `if [[ "/" != "$dir ]] && [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then rm -fr "$dir"; fi`.  But having an `rm -fr $var` is exceedingly dangerous and you should look very carefully at whether there is any other way to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if some part of the deletion would violate permissions. For example

```
$ mkdir -p p/q
$ sudo chown root p p/q
$ sudo chmod 700 p p/q
$ rm -rf p
rm: cannot remove 'p': Permission denied
$ echo $?
1
```

Note, however, that you *can* remove a directory that's not yours from a directory that is. So the above would not fail if I only tried with `p` without the "contents".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you don't have permission to remove `$dir` the `rm` will fail, with `-r` I assume it will fail if anything at all cannot be deleted.

For example,

```
$ mkdir test_dir
$ sudo chown root.root test_dir
$ cd test_dir # we no longer have write permission to .
$ sudo mkdir new_dir
$ rm -rf new_dir
rm: cannot remove 'new_dir': Permission denied
$ echo $?
1
```